# Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x, faces-config, facescontext

Hi I'm migrating my application from Websphere to Jboss and I'm getting below error while deploying my EAR. I would really appreciate if anyone could hint the error.

I'm also getting error stating org.apache.myfaces.tiles.example.TilesBacking could not be loaded.

```
09:37:57,297 ERROR [org.jboss.as.jsf] (MSC service thread 1-23) JBAS012600: Could not load JSF managed bean class: org.apache.myfaces.tiles.example.TilesBacking
09:37:58,136 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 165) JBAS018210: Register web context: /DIDWeb
09:38:11,638 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 165) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.28-jbossorg-2  for context '/DIDWeb'
09:38:12,489 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 165) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:376) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:216) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [rt.jar:1.6.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_101]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682) [rt.jar:1.6.0_101]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at javax.faces.application.Application.getResourceHandler(Application.java:287) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.setResourceHandler(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:766) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:313) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:222) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:361) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        ... 13 more
```

Below is my example-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.0//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_0.dtd" [
<!ENTITY managed-beans_gen          SYSTEM "managed-beans_gen.xml">
<!ENTITY sample-navigation-rules    SYSTEM "sample-navigation-rules.xml">
 <!ENTITY converters_gen    SYSTEM "converters_gen.xml">
]>

<faces-config>
    <application>
        <view-handler>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.jsp.JspTilesViewHandlerImpl</view-handler>
    </application>

    <!-- managed beans of UMDID app -->
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>tilesBacking</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>org.apache.myfaces.tiles.example.TilesBacking</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>scrAttrBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.util.ScrAttrBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>emailValidator</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.validator.EmailValidator</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>pageMessages</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.util.PageMessages</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <!-- js3634 xfer1x 011107 -->
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>editRangeBBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.backingbean.editrange.EditRangeBBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <!-- js3634 xxxxx 111406 -->
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>findAvailDidBBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.backingbean.findavaildid.FindAvailDidBBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <!-- js3634 xexisting1x 121406 -->
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>findExistDidBBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.backingbean.findexistdid.FindExistDidBBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>queryDidBBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.backingbean.querydid.QueryDidBBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>updateContactBBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.backingbean.updatecntct.UpdateContactBBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>InventoryReportBBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.backingbean.inventoryreport.InventoryReportBBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>ReconciliationReportBBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.backingbean.reconciliationreport.ReconciliationReportBBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>transHistBBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.backingbean.transhist.TransHistBBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <!-- js3634 xar1x 012206 -->
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>addRangeBBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.backingbean.addrange.AddRangeBBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <!-- js3634 xfer1x 011107 -->
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>editRangeData</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.data.editrange.EditRangeData</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <!-- js3634 xar1x 012207 -->
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>addRangeData</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.data.addrange.AddRangeData</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>transHistData</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.data.transhist.TransHistData</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <!-- js3634 xxxxx 111406 -->
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>findAvailDidData</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.data.findavaildid.FindAvailDidData</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <!-- js3634 xexisting2x 121406 -->
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>findExistDidData</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.data.findexistdid.FindExistDidData</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>queryDidData</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.data.querydid.QueryDidData</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>updateContactData</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.data.updatecntct.UpdateContactData</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>umdidPageMsgData</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.data.UmdidPageMsgData</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>phoneNumberValidator</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.validator.PhoneNumberValidator</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>appPrivileges</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.util.AppPrivileges</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>navMenuBBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.backingbean.navmenu.NavMenuBBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <!-- js3634 102006
        changed below from to
        com.att.umdid.jsf.util.umdidPageMessages -->
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>umdidPageMessages</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.att.umdid.jsf.util.PageMessages</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <!-- navigation rules of UMDID app -->

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>

        <!-- js3634 020807 -->
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_editrangepage</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/EditRange.jsp</to-view-id>   
            <redirect/>     
        </navigation-case>

        <!-- js3634 031907 -->
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_splitrange</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/SplitRange.jsp</to-view-id>        
        </navigation-case>

        <!-- js3634 xar6x 013007 -->
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_addrangedone</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/AddRange.jsp</to-view-id>      
            <redirect/> 
        </navigation-case>

        <!-- js3634 xxxxx 111406 -->
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_findavaildidpage</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/FindAvailDid.jsp</to-view-id>          
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_findcallhubswitchdidpage</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/FindAvailDid.jsp</to-view-id>          
        </navigation-case>


        <!-- js3634 xexisting1x 121406 -->
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_findexistdidpage</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/FindExistDid.jsp</to-view-id>          
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_querydidpage</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/QueryDid.jsp</to-view-id>          
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_found_inventoryreport</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/inventoryreport.jsp</to-view-id>           
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_found_reconciliationreport</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/reconciliationreport.jsp</to-view-id>          
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_transhistpage</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/TransHist.jsp</to-view-id>         
        </navigation-case>

        <!-- js3634 xxxxx 111406 -->
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_foundavaildid</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/FindAvailDid.jsp</to-view-id>          
        </navigation-case>

        <!-- js3634 xexisting2x 121406 -->
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_foundexistdid</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/FindExistDid.jsp</to-view-id>          
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_foundquerydid</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/QueryDid.jsp</to-view-id>          
        </navigation-case>

        <!-- js3634 xfer1x 011107 -->
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_foundrange</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/FindRange.jsp</to-view-id>         
        </navigation-case>
        <!-- js3634 xar1x 012207 -->
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_addrangepage</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/AddRange.jsp</to-view-id>          
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_searchaddrange</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/AddRange.jsp</to-view-id>          
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_updatecontactpage</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/UpdateContact.jsp</to-view-id>         
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_foundcontact</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/UpdateContact.jsp</to-view-id>         
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_logout</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/logout.jsp</to-view-id>
            <!--<redirect/>-->
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_error</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/error.jsp</to-view-id>
            <!--<redirect/>-->
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go_logoutRedirect</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/jsp/LogoutRedirect.jsp</to-view-id>
            <!--<redirect/>-->
        </navigation-case>

    </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could hint the error.